# Add or replace into array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I add or replace into existing array of objects. Lets say I have existing array like this:

```
productOffer.view = [
  {id: 1, name: "john"},
  {id: 2, name: "Sam"}
]

productOffer.view.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(el.id == productOffer.createId){
        productOffer.view[i] = ajaxCall.responseJSON
    } else {
        productOffer.view.push(ajaxCall.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

Tried the following but the values are getting replaced instead of adding:

```
productOffer.hashedArr = productOffer.hash(productOffer.view);
productOffer.view.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(el.id == productOffer.createId){
        productOffer.hashedArr[i] = ajaxCall.responseJSON
    } else {
        productOffer.hashedArr[i] = el;
    }
});

for(var key in productOffer.hashedArr){
    productOffer.view = [];
    productOffer.view.push(productOffer.hashedArr[key]);
}


hash: function(arr){
    var arrIndex = Object.create(null);
    arr.forEach(function(el){
        arrIndex[el.id] = el;
    });
    console.log('hash ', arrIndex);
    return arrIndex;
},
```

Comment: If you can use a library, i suggest you to test lodash: https://lodash.com/ It can help you working with arrays, collections and objects.

Comment: I disagree, LoDash becomes pretty much useless when you master `.filter`, `.map` and other pretty powerful methods JS arrays have out of the box.

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to add something to the object in the array, or do you want to add in the array?

Comment: @KristjanKica add to array

Comment: use push perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't `hash: function(arr){` give you a syntay error and crash your script?? What does your console say?

Comment: @JeremyThille hash function is inside object

Comment: Not in the code you provided.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex()` to check if object with same id exists in array and if it does replace it with new object or if it doesn't push new object to array.

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "john"},
  {id: 2, name: "Sam"}
]

function addOrReplace(data, obj) {
  var i = data.findIndex(function(e) {
    return e.id == obj.id;
  });

  i != -1 ? data[i] = obj : data.push(obj);
  return data;
}

console.log(addOrReplace(arr, {id: 1, name: "lorem"}))
console.log(addOrReplace(arr, {id: 3, name: "ipsum"}))
```

Comment: Could you please show this `var i = data.findIndex(e => e.id == obj.id);` in simple js

Comment: Thanks for introducing `findIndex()` but what is wrong with my hashing function?